# import *.pdf into my app iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

how to import *.pdf all pdf from my iphone to my app like this add music file. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html .Thanks in advance .New to iphone dev.Really appreciate any help.

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    NSFileManager *mgr = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

    NSArray *allFiles = [mgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundlePath   error:NULL];
    for (NSString *fileName in allFiles)
    {
        if ([[fileName pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"pdf"])
        {
            NSString *fullFilePath = [bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
            // fullFilePath now contains the path to your pdf file
         //   DoSomethingWithFile(fullFilePath);

            NSLog(@"file: %@",fullFilePath);

        }
    }

    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"" withExtension: @"pdf"];

    NSLog(@"File: %@",url);
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: From your code it seems this pdf file is already present in your application's bundle and all you want to know is how to get a hold of it?

Comment: yes the code above is for that but I wanted to see all pdf's from the iphone how do I change that or what  path do I need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just browse all the files on the phone from within your App.

As I said to you in the comment on your other questions (which, by the way is almost exactly the same as this one, but in the other question you ask about csv files rather than pdf), you need to read up about the App Sandbox.

In a nutshell, Apps can only see their own files and those that are written by the App. All apps have their own storage space and they can only see in that area.

Having said that, it is possible to pass some files around between apps, but they have to be written to support that. There is no such concept as a global file system on iOS devices.

[READ THIS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html)

Comment: Thanks Nick again. I had got code to ADD Music from apple dev site which I have mentioned above .SO I was wondering if it had something to do with the app.So the right way to go about it is to host a file on server sand parse data or get data into the APP.I even checked ibook app and even the pdf present in the iphone is not recognized .Looks like you need to import it from the server itself right?

Answer (score 2):

You can just email the pdf file as attachment and the iphone can read it on its own. That feature already exists within the iOS of the iPhone or you could upload them somewhere (on your server) and send the links.

Comment: I need to see all pdf from iphone received from bluetooth